# Why does VirtualBox spawn so many processes on Linux?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox version 4.1.12_Ubuntur77245. Following is a screenshot of the command `htop`. Why does virtualbox spawn multiple processes for a single VM?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those aren't processes, they're threads. As indicated by the graph, all but the top one are threads spawned by the main process 3164. (Each thread also gets its own PID in Linux.)

You can press `H` in htop to collapse or expand process threads.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but I would expect there to be at least one host thread per virtual CPU, and depending on how deep the paravirtualization goes, perhaps as many as one host thread per thread executing *within* the virtual machine.

Comment: @zwol I'd expect a thread per vCPU and threads for virtual hardware devices.

Comment: Don't forget about threads for other stuff like `Clipboard sharing` and `Drag & Drop`.